# how to know how much time/% is left for document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

i usually do

```
$('#load').show();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load').hide();
});
```

where `<div id="load">` has just a animated gif

but i was thinking of improve a little bit and show a progressbar

having

```
<div id="load"><div id="done"></div></div>
```

so i could, in a timeout (i guess)

```
var percent_done = how_do_i_figure_out(); /*  here is where i need help */
$('#done').width(percent_done);
```

Comment: There is no way of knowing how much of the DOM has been generated.

Comment: mi first guess is to have an animate({width:'100%'},average_load_time) but that just...

Comment: @KevinB so is that what gmail does? (my last commment)

Comment: I believe this is fairly impossible to find out because `.ready` fires once **all** resources (images, swfs... etc) have been loaded completely...

Comment: Like my father used to say, "It'll be done when it's done".

Comment: I don't know what gmail does, i don't use it. It is possible to make a fake progress bar that progresses over x milliseconds regardless of the "amount done" that the page actually is.

Comment: @jperovid `.ready` does not wait for images and swfs to be loaded.

Comment: @jperovic no, you're thinking about the "load" event. The "ready" event (or pseudo-event) fires when the DOM is built, but possibly before images are loaded.

Comment: @Pointy i think you are talking about $(function(){}) i am pretty sure document.ready waits for images

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet `$(function(){})` **is** the "ready" handler, and I'm afraid you're mistaken. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) is the MDN description of the "load" event for the `window`, and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) is the Firefox version of the "ready" event.

Comment: what do you think of the approach? (animate till 95 very slow and on ready animate the rest fast) check http://funcook.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It can't be done!**

You have no access to elements not rendered yet, so how would you know what is missing?!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet the browser does not make that information available.

Comment: But lets say its a known value, var page_weight = 600 /*kB*/ .is there a way to know how many kB have been downloaded? if so, it couldbe percent_left = downladed()/page_weight*100 (or something)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet. **1.** Pictures aren't loaded in the ready event. **2.** Why do you "know" the kb for each page. **I can continue with the list, but there is no point...** just forget it or fake it to please someone...

Comment: Uncertainty over timing could be reduced by reporting back t_ready and t_load via ajax to the server after page load, and running a heuristic for every page independently. However the heuristic would take some effort to develop and the variability in timing may be so large as to make the exercise no better than an estimate based on page weight or a good guess.

Comment: what do you think of the approach? (animate till 95 very slow and on ready animate the rest fast) check http://funcook.com @gdoron

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet. I think intelligent persons would see it's a fake! Just show a "Please Wait until the page load" message so you won't loose the site "integrity".

Comment: @gdoron well, maybe in  a webiste like this (we are all programmers) but in a random webiste; i think that 0.05% people would notice

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a fake progressbar. Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/dM8Qp/1/

It is not possible to know how long it is going to be before the `DOMready` event happens.

html

```
<div id="pb"></div>​
```

js

```
$("#pb").progressbar();
var preloader = $("<div />").css("height", "0px").animate({
    height: 95
}, {
    step: function() {
        //console.log(Math.ceil(parseFloat($(this).css("height"))))
        $("#pb").progressbar("value", Math.ceil(parseFloat($(this).css("height"))));
    },
    duration: 2000
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    preloader.promise().done(function(){
        $("#pb").add(preloader).remove();
    });
});
```

Updated per gdoron's suggestion in comments.

Comment: I would fill the progress-bar to max 95%, then when the DOM is ready change it to 100% then hide it. Anyway fake a progress-bar isn't the best practice, _Please Wait_ sounds like a better solution.

Comment: @gdoron Agreed, though sometimes you just have to please your client. Here's the filamentgroup website that implements that same kind of functionality (no progress bar): http://www.filamentgroup.com/

Comment: i used you idea but just with a simple animate(width) funcook.com its not that bad, huh? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables to propertly determine how much time it will take to load.  Some that can't be calculated (like internet connection speed).